# Double slash in upload URLs

Tags: uploads, options

Wordpress is automatically adding a trailing slash to my custom upload folder in Settings » Media. This is causing upload URLs (for example, for images uploaded through the Media Uploader) to get a double slash, as in example.com/files//myfile.jpg

Here's what happens:

1. I go to Settings » Media
2. Under **Uploading Files** in the field labeled **Store uploads in this folder**, I type in `files`, with no trailing slash. (This is consistent with the example listed next to the text field: `Default is wp-content/uploads`)
3. Hit "Save Changes"
4. The page reloads, and the upload folder is now `files/`, with a trailing slash.

I have tested other URLs (`files/myfiles`, `uploads`), and Wordpress always adds a trailing slash when I hit save. I have **Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders** unchecked.

What gives? How do I fix this?

I am on 3.3.1, but this was happening in 3.2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an `untrailingslashit()` also.